# PHP Sort Array of Numeric Filenames

Tags: php, sorting

Have code that right now creates and array of a directory that has text files and gets their modified date and then sorts descending then slices and echos each individually with other parameters.

I am changing it to get the files in a directory and sort by filename which are numeric and then I want it sorted descending then sliced then echoed.

```
$files_listed = array();
foreach (glob('dir/*.txt') as $quip) {
    $files_listed[filemtime($quip)] = $quip;
}
krsort($files_listed);
$master_arc = array_slice($files_listed, 0, 5, true);

// array
foreach($master_arc as $step) {

$arc = file($step, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// print
include 'echo.php';

}
```

I tried scandir and nothing showed up

```
$files_listed = array();
$dir = 'dir/';
$files_listed = scandir($dir, 1);
$master_arc = array_slice($files_listed, 0, 5, true);

// array
foreach($master_arc as $step) {

$arc = file($step, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// print
include 'echo.php';

}
```

I tried just removing filemtime and it also failed so I am lost.

```
$files_listed = array();
foreach (glob('dir/*.txt') as $quip) {
    $files_listed = $quip;
}
arsort($files_listed);
$master_arc = array_slice($files_listed, 0, 5, true);

// array
foreach($master_arc as $step) {

$arc = file($step, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// print
include 'echo.php';

}
```

Comment: try $files_listed[] since you're appending to an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me.

```
<?php

$files_listed = array();

foreach (glob('*.txt') as $quip) {
    $files_listed[] = $quip;
}

arsort($files_listed);
$master_arc = array_slice($files_listed, 0, 5, true);

// array
foreach($master_arc as $step) {
print_r($step);

$arc = file($step, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
print_r($arc);

}
```